# Browsing images on SD card via Canon EOS SDK (c++)

Tags: c++, edsdk, canon-sdk

I can succesfully download to disk the picture that has been just shot using kEdsSaveTo_Host and catching the event.

However, for various reasons i need to not download it to the pc immediately but to shoot, then browse what is available on the camera, get the latest image, and delete it.

Is this possible with the canon SDK ? I can't really go past using kEdsSaveTo_Camera. How do i browse the SD? how do i download an image? Is it something i can do with the canon sdk or should i simply release the cameras, and then use windows API to browse the content, download and delete the image?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the file system with calling EdsGetChildCount, EdsGetChildAtIndex and EdsGetVolumeInfo or EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo.

Basically, call EdsGetChildCount with the camera pointer as parameter to get the number of volumes.
Go through every volume with EdsGetChildAtIndex (again with the camera pointer as parameter) and call EdsGetVolumeInfo with the volume pointer from the EdsGetChildAtIndex call to get information about the volume.

With each volume you can do the same as before the get files and folders but instead of the camera pointer you pass the volume pointer to it.
To get information about the file or folder use EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo.
The struct that this function returns states if it's a folder or file.

If it's a folder you can repeat the above again but of course use the folders pointer instead of the volumes.

To download a file you can do the same as you do with SaveTo_Host and use the files pointer.

If you don't mind reading C# I have implemented all of that in this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp

You can find the most relevant part at the bottom of the Camera.cs file.

Comment: thank you, that's really helpful. Any idea if it's possible to delete files as well ?

Comment: @Andrea, no problem! and sure, just call EdsDeleteDirectoryItem with the file/folder pointer you got from calling EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo

Comment: thank you so much! I missed that since i kept looking for an EdsDeleteFile or similar so i didn't even bother to read the EdsDeleteDirectoryItem. Completely my bad, i was going bananas =) thank you for being a positive SO user, taking the time to point out something in the documentation (albeit, in my defense, a bit hidden :P )

Comment: @Andrea, you're welcome :) and no worries, it happens ;) I've been reading that thing up and down so many times and stumbled upon odd details even more often, so it's a pleasure to help out a fellow lost soul :))

Comment: I just wanted to thank you once again. I managed to do everything i needed to. 

The fact that the code samples on the documentation are broken were throwing me off, your simple pseudocode explanation helped me a lot. Way better than the official documentation. Really really thank you.

Comment: @Andrea, no problem! yeah, the documentation is not very good with outdated examples and wrong or missing descriptions. but it's all there is.

Comment: Hey there, one more question if you don't mind. 

All i can see in the documentation are

(-Notification of file creation
-Notification of file deletion
-Notification of changes in file information
-Notification of changes in the volume information of r
-Notification of requests to update volume information
-Notification of requests to update folder information
-Notification of file transfer requests
-Notification of direct transfer requests
-Notification of requests to cancel direct transfer)

but i need simply a notification "file ready for transfer". Is there one? thanks!

Comment: @Andrea, hey! sure, it's "Notification of file transfer requests" or in code it's called DirItemRequestTransfer. But I though you already have that. Or are you asking for something different?

Comment: Mh, unless i fsckd up pretty bad, i get that event only on kEdsSaveTo_Host. It doesn't fire with kEdsSaveTo_Camera. Should it?

Comment: @Andrea, ah yes that's correct. When you use SaveTo_Camera the file creation event is what you want. Of course, in theory it could be any file but that's so unlikely that you can assume it's the photo you just took. If you want to be more sure, you can check out the file name and it's ongoing number (again with EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo)

Comment: @Andrea, sure, no problem!